# How to replicate the function of the tilde character in LaTeX?

Tags: html

In LaTeX [the tilde character](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Text_Formatting#Non-breaking_spaces) is used set a space between two text elements that cannot be separated by a line break. This is useful to keep citations right next to the citing text, for instance. It is also most useful when presenting figures according to the ISU. As an example, the code:

```
1~400~t/a
```

Guarantees the following text output, always packed together in the same line:

> 1 400 t/a

Is there a way to mimic this behaviour in HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A non-breaking space, in HTML, is expressed as `&nbsp;`